# How does someone attain immortality by sacrifice?

Tags: vedas, vedanta

```
न कर्मणा न प्रजया धनेन त्यागेनैके अमृतत्वमानशुः ।
परेण नाकं निहितं गुहायां विभ्राजते तद्यतयो विशन्ति ॥
na karmaṇā na prajayā dhanena tyāgenaike amṛtatvamānaśuḥ .
pareṇa nākaṃ nihitaṃ guhāyāṃ vibhrājate tadyatayo viśanti
```

The first line says that one will attain immortality by sacrifice alone and not by deeds, not by progeny, not by wealth.

How can someone even attain immortality? We have heard of great people like king Bali who sacrificed many things and even their lives and they are remembered till to this date. And also we have seen in the history about people who wanted to live long and immortal have got slayed by the supreme. At the end, all humans are mortal.

Why is the above sloka saying that sacrificing makes immortal? What is sacrifice meant here in this sloka?

Comment: Immortal (Amrut) does not mean living with body forever - Nobody, even devas, can live forever ever. They just live reallly long. Amrut means realizing that we (Atma) cannot be destroyed and attaining Moksha.

Comment: Nobody can live forever.

Comment: you need to give the source of your quote. The quote does not make sense, you do not attain immortality through sacrifice.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda the source is from Kaivalya Upanishad, Sanyasa Sukta. It doesn't make sense for you. But, still it exists in upanishads.